# Login command for a webpage

Tags: html, authentication

I'm trying to put a simple login command for a webpage but it doesn't work.
Upon placing the correct username and password in the login field the page it should direct you to an external website (Amazon.com)
If the username is incorrect the link should default to your first page (homepage.html)

```
 <HEAD>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function LogIn(){
  loggedin=false;
  alert("Correct")
  username="admin";
  password="pass";
  username=prompt("Username: all lowercase 'username'","");
  username=username.toLowerCase();
  password=prompt("Password: all lowercase 'password'","");
  password=password.toLowerCase();
     if (username=="username" && password=="password") {
     loggedin=true;
     window.location="http://www.amazon.com";
     }
     if (loggedin==false) {
     alert("Invalid login!");
     window.location="homepage.html";
     }
   }
</SCRIPT> 
<center>
<form><input type=button value="Login!" onClick="LogIn()"></form>
</center>
```

Comment: This will provide no security at all, as the JavaScript code can easily be viewed by anyone in their browser. For real security, you'd need a server-side login (but that comes with a lot of other requirements). Really depends on what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: This looks like a login page of 100 years old app...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for several reasons:

1. You store user input in the same variable where you store correct credentials.
2. You compare these variables with strings "username" and "password". In your example username/password is the correct login.

So a slightly better code would be:

```
var correctUsername = "admin";
var username = prompt("Username: all lowercase 'username'","");
if (username == correctUsername)...
```

Also, keep in mind that the approach you are taking is not secure enough to be used in any real web-page.

Answer (score 0):

From the code I see, You compare string with variable . The condition should be like this way:

```
if (username=="admin" && password=="pass")
```

Comment: Wow and so? How does this help? Won't this always return true? `#CommonSenseFail`

Comment: So what's the change from the OP's question?

Comment: he takes username as a string instead of username's value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U were overriding the username and password

so just create 2 variables as

```
var correctUsername = "admin";
var username = prompt("Username: all lowercase 'username'","");
if (username == correctUsername)
```

or use the if condition as shown

```
<HEAD>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function LogIn(){
  loggedin=false;
  alert("Correct")

  username=prompt("Username: all lowercase 'username'","");
  username=username.toLowerCase();
  password=prompt("Password: all lowercase 'password'","");
  password=password.toLowerCase();
     if (username=="admin" && password=="pass") {
     loggedin=true;
     window.location="http://www.amazon.com";
     }
     if (loggedin==false) {
     alert("Invalid login!");
     window.location="homepage.html";
     }
   }
</SCRIPT> 
<center>
<form><input type=button value="Login!" onClick="LogIn()"></form>
</center>
```